# Converting HTML to plain text in C#

Tags: c#, html

I am having HTML content. How can i convert it into plain text so that i can so it in a label.

```
lbl1.Text = htmlEditor1.Html;
```

Any suggestion !

Comment: Is there a reason to show this in a label? As Thomas advised you, you could throw away all tags, but the layout won't be nice... It might be an alternativ to show your html within a browser control.

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex.Replace(htmlEditor1.Html, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

will strip all HTML tags if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this before?

```
var plaintext = HtmlFilter.ConvertToPlainText(htmlContent);
```